# Gap between edge of lattice and mesh when using simple deform

Tags: modeling, modifiers, lattice

I'm stumped, I can't figure out what's going on here. I've got a lattice and a plane with identical x & z dimensions. When I use a Simple Deform Bend of 360 degrees on the lattice, the edges meet seamlessly to create a cylinder - but the edge of the plane don't. It's as if there's a gap being created between the edges of the plane and the edge of the lattice.

All transforms are applied apart from the y scaling on the lattice. Changing that back to 1 doesn't change anything, and neither does moving the empty I'm using as the origin for the deform. The solidify is just there to show what's going on from the top view - removing it makes no difference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Lattice properties, change the interpolation from *B-Spline* to *Linear*. There is by default a smooth interpolation between the control points when using a Lattice.

[image]

Side note, for this kind of transformation, you only need a 1-dimensional lattice.

Result, with a *Weld* and a *Solidify* modifier :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This has indeed fixed the problem. And thanks for the tip about the 1D lattice!